# C# Webdriver - Page Title assert fails before page loads

Tags: c#, selenium, visual-studio-2012, webdriver

This issue began when I switched from testing on the www website to my localhost version of it.  Working in VS 2012, I will begin debugging so the localhost is active, detach the process so I can test on it, then run any test I like.  For a very basic example:

```
    [Test]
    public void CanGoToHomePage()
    {
        Pages.HomePage.Goto();
        Assert.IsTrue(Pages.HomePage.IsAt());
    }
```

And the functions it references are here:

```
    public class HomePage
    {
        const string Url = "http://localhost:3738";
        const string HomepageTitle = "FunnelFire - Home Page";

        public void Goto()
        {
            Browser.Goto(Url);
        }

        public bool IsAt()
        {
            return Browser.Title == HomepageTitle;
        }
    }
```

And the actual selenium code here:

```
    public static class Browser
    {
        static IWebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();

        public static void Goto(string url)
        {
            webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            webDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            webDriver.Url = url;
        }
    }
```

Now the issue.  The 10 second implicit wait that I added in Browser does successfully wait at most 10 seconds after loading a page to see if it can locate whatever information I want it to find, that is not the problem.

As I said earlier, after I switched to testing on localhost, suddenly I ran into a strange issue where a page would begin to load (i.e. screen still totally white, nothing finished) or even sometimes the next page would JUST barely finish loading and suddenly the test would just up and fail, pointing to the Assert of IsAt returning false even though the page it was loading was the correct one.  I could run that test immediately once more and it would pass without a problem.  Run it a third time and it could randomly fail again.  I'm honestly not sure what is causing the issue and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you try running the project NOT in debug mode? Do you still get the same result in that case?

Comment: For a start, remove the implicit wait. Do not call it constantly, call it once and it is set for the life of the driver. What version of Firefox and Selenium is this? I would suggest that **while** Selenium attempts to visit that page, visit that page manually, yourself, in a seperate browser instance. It will help show if Selenium really is the issue.

Comment: @Pat: I did try "Start without debugging" and it seemed to make the issue less frequent but it remains.

Comment: @Arran This code may have misled you but "Goto" is only called once and everything else branches off from it, so it is only called once and is set for the life of the driver. I can also assure you there is no issue with the page itself, but either the selenium or the fact that i'm trying to test on the page in localhost.  Also it seems someone else has given me some advice on an explicit wait below which I will try in a minute.

Answer (score 7):

Implicit waits work **only** for finding elements. For waiting on the title of the page to be a certain value, you'll want to use an explicit wait. You can write your own version of this pattern, but in the .NET bindings, the `WebDriver.Support.dll` assembly has a `WebDriverWait` class to help with this. Its use would look something like this:

```
// WARNING! Untested code written from memory below. It has not
// been tested or even compiled in an IDE, so may be syntactically
// incorrect. The concept, however, should still be valid. 
public void WaitForTitle(IWebDriver driver, string title, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
    wait.Until((d) => { return d.Title == title; });
}
```

You could even modify your `IsAt` method to use this pattern, catching the `WebDriverTimeoutException` and returning false if the wait function times out.

Comment: Hi Jim, I can't seem to properly get my code in a block in the comments here like yours, but I've used what you wrote there with minor tweaking and modified my IsAt() to use a try/catch with the WebDriverTimeoutException.  It compiles and has successfully gotten to the homepage and returned true so far, so hopefully this solves the issue (though I'll never know for sure unless I eventually fail something haha).  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer as the correct one, then. And the mini-markdown tags can be revealed by clicking the "help" link next to the comment edit field. The way to mark pieces of comments as blocks is the same as in the main questions and answers, by surrounding the term with backquotes (`).