# How do I reliably check the current page after navigation in Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

In my web tests using Selenium WebDriver and IEDriverServer.exe 2.32.3.0, I need to check the title of the current page after navigating to a certain URL. Here's the code:

```
_webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("...");
Assert.That(_webDriver.Title, Is.EqualTo("..."));
```

This sometimes works, but sporadically breaks - the title is not as expected (but still the one from the page before).

I've read on StackOverflow ([C# Webdriver - Page Title assert fails before page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904172/c-sharp-webdriver-page-title-assert-fails-before-page-loads)) that `IWebDriver.Title` property does not auto-wait for navigation to complete (why doesn't it?), but instead you need to manually wait using the `WebDriverWait` API.

I implemented manual waiting for the title:

```
 var wait = new WebDriverWait(_webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds (3.0));
 wait.Until(d => d.Title == expectedTitle);
```

However, this sometimes waits for 3 seconds, then throws a `WebDriverTimeoutException`. The build agent running the code is quite fast and the web site I'm testing is trivial (just starting development), so I'm quite sure that it can't really take 3 seconds to navigate. I noticed that on the other StackOverflow question, the original poster also got the `WebDriverTimeoutException` and just caught and ignored it.

I found that solution a little flaky, so I tried a different workaround. I gave the `<title>` attribute an ID in my HTML and used IWebDriver.FindElement, which is supposed to wait for the page to complete:

```
Assert.That(_webDriver.FindElement(By.Id(ViewIDs.Shared._Layout.Title)).Text, Is.EqualTo(page.ExpectedTitle));
```

At first, that seemed to work. However, it doesn't reliably, it sometimes throws:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : Unable to find element with id == _Layout-title
 at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse)
 at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
 at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.FindElement(String mechanism, String value)
 at OpenQA.Selenium.By.FindElement(ISearchContext context)
 at ...
```

(I also tried upgrading to WebDriver/IEDriverServer 2.33.0.0; but in that version, the text of the `<title>` tag is always empty...)

Hence my question. How do I reliably check the current page after navigation in Selenium WebDriver? Is there a good pattern that works?

Comment: Is this on a remote machine? Is it any different on any other drivers? Have you actually verified it works locally?

Comment: This is on a build agent, where IEDriverServer and test runner are on the same machine. Both approaches (explicit waiting and finding the title element) work fine most of the time, both locally and remotely. They've failed only on the build agent so far, but the build agent runs the tests far more often than I do locally.

Comment: Can't say if it's any different with the other drivers, we need IE to work. Actually, I'd just like to know what is the _right_ way to do what I want to do. Also, it's a little hard to reproduce, since it only fails every now and then.

(When I said "remotely" above, I actually meant "on the build agent".)

Comment: @user1177636: There are a few reasons why I'm trying to assert the current page after navigation. First, I'm trying to implement the [Page Object pattern](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects). Second, I like to fail early and descriptively, and when navigation takes me to an unexpected page, I'd rather fail with "wrong page" than "element not found". Third, sometimes I have tests that consist only of checking the result of a navigation, e.g., after navigating to URL '/', the LoginPage should be shown. Or, after clicking "Log out", the user is redirected to the LoginPage again.

Comment: @user1177636: And you're right, a 3 seconds wait won't hurt if necessary. However, when I use the WebDriverWait class, which seems to be designed for this purpose, it times out without giving me the correct title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run into very similar issues.  I still have not been able to tell why but often if you try to use an element without doing a isElementPresent check it will fail occasionally.  My solution is mildly "expensive" but I have not found a reliable alternative as yet.

My example is in java, shouldn't be hard to translate but I don't have the libraries.

```
    waitForElement("_Layout-title", 45);
```

then continue with your code

```
    Assert.That(_webDriver.FindElement(By.Id(ViewIDs.Shared._Layout.Title)).Text, Is.EqualTo(page.ExpectedTitle));
```

This tries a set number of times, in this case 45, to find the element.  Once id=_Layout-title is present it will continue to the next line of code and do the assert.  While it isn't perfect, it did make my test much more stable.

Comment: Tanks for the answer, I'm glad I'm not the only one with this problem. But I'm still hoping there must be some better way of doing this than retrying 45 times or waiting for a few seconds.

Answer (score 3):

I just solved it with stuff I derived from something I found on [CodeProject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150685/how-do-i-reliably-check-the-current-page-after-navigation-in-selenium-webdriver):

```
private void WaitUntilLoaded()
{
    var wait = new OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(%));
    wait.Until(x =>
    {
        return ((IJavaScriptExecutor)this.driver)
        .ExecuteScript("return document.readyState").Equals("complete");
    });
}
```

According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_readystate.asp) it works for most popular browsers.

As I presently test on Firefox I ended up on [Mozilla's own page](https://blog.mozilla.org/webqa/2012/07/12/how-to-webdriverwait/) about how to recognise a page as loaded. IMHO read worth to avoid dragons.

That gave me

```
wait.Until(p => p.FindElement(
    By.Id("somethingThatIsDisplayedWhenMyAsyncronousStuffIsFinished")
    ).Displayed);
```

which saved my day.

Comment: Might there still be a race condition if `document.readyState` is read before the browser actually starts navigating to the other page?

Comment: @FabianSchmied My code looks something like `Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(...);WaitUntilLoaded();` and I _guess_ Selenium handles it in order as navigating between pages are quite central to testing a web solution.